# How to prevent another user from editing my display name in Empathy?

Tags: empathy

How can I prevent another user from editing my Empathy display name?
Since I am using shared computer, is there any solution?
I have administrative privileges.

Comment: Set up different user accounts for each user, or, at least, a separate account just for yourself, and make sure the autologin is disabled.

Comment: Seconding @mikewhatever 's suggestion.  Setup separate accounts for the other users, preferably without administrative privileges.

Answer (score 3):

Set up different user accounts for each user, or, a separate account just for yourself with autologin disabled, and a shared account for everyone else.